# Method to remove small unwanted region and fill holes for specific image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a binary image that maintains some unwanted region (small white dot) and hole regions (in figure 1). My idea is that to fill the object after I will remove the unwanted region but I don't now exactly wich method can help me

[image: the original image]

[image: wanted image]

Comment: this image is taken after applying median filter

Answer (score 1):

For this image in particular? I believe it should be sufficient to threshold (to get a binary image with only the visible particles present), then perform area opening (remove all objects with an area smaller than a certain value). Then, depending on how the remaining object looks, perform morphological operations such as thickening (simply enlarge the object) and closing (to fill in holes).

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to achieve it.

1) use Morphological Transformations + Thresholding.

2) Aditionally you can use Contour-detection, so the largest contour-area is the object you want to fill.